# 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' error while searchin string in text file-Python

Tags: python, regex, search

Have created a simple text file with the contents bellow:

```
1001
bread
20
10
1002
sugar
10
7
1003
ice
14
10
```

The following Python script bellow was meant to search and find a string within the text file and display the result. Where is the error coming from? what amendments can i do to the code?

```
import re
with open('dbase.txt', 'r') as x:
    y=x.readlines()
    z=list(y)

    word = ['ice']
    for i in word:
        if re.search(i, z):
            print('found a match!')
        else:
            print('not found')
```

Comment: With `y=x.readlines()` you already have a list, `z=list(y)` looks redundant. To read the whole file into a variable, you ned `z=x.read()` (remove `y=x.readlines()`). Do you mean to display *line* where `word`s are found or just `match!` for each `word` found in the whole text?

Comment: `y = x.read()` and `for i in word: i in y` should be enough.

Comment: Your `re.search` needs a pattern to match. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search

Comment: Not necessarily showing line in which its found, but just finding it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
FOUND = False
with open('dbase.txt', 'r') as x:
    for line in x.readlines():
        if line.strip() == 'ice':
            FOUND = True
            break

if FOUND:
    print("Found the ICE")
else:
    print("Couldn't find the ICE")
```

And the error you are seeing is because of the incorrect argument passed to the re.search function. It doesn't accept an array/list as an argument

see the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)

Answer (score 2):

You're searching a list but you probably want to search a string.

You don't need regex for this. In your case the best solution is probably.

```
with open('dbase.txt') as file:
    words = ['ice']
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file, 1):
         split_line = line.split()  # a list of all words on that line
         for word in words:
              if word in split_line:
                  print('found "{}" on line {}'.format(word, line_number))
              else:
                  print('did not find "{}" on line {}'.format(word, line_number))
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the code and adding a split() to text because "dice" would return true

Answer (score 0):

readlines() is returning a list so `z=list(y)` is unnecessary.
If you want to read the file one line at a time you can simply use a for loop on it:

```
import re
with open('dbase.txt', 'r') as x:
    word = ['ice'] # put it there to avoid redefining it for each line
    for line in x:
            for i in word:
                if re.search(i, line):
                    print('found a match!')
                else:
                    print('not found')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(blah.txt, "rt") as f:
#your code here
```

Read it all as text.